# When the connection is done with ldap for PHP?

Tags: php, networking, ldap

I'm trying to understand PHP's ldap function in order to debug an app.

The authentication flow is like following:

```
ldap_connect($host, $port);

ldap_set_option($ds, $option);

ldap_bind($ds, $rdn, $pwd);

ldap_search($smth);

ldap_get_entries($smtgelse);

ldap_close($ds);
```

The error I get is:

```
The gateway did not receive a timely response from the upstream server or application.
```

I suspect a firewall to block the response, but I put a logger to see which statment is blocking, it's the `ldap_bind` one's.

If it's a network issue it should block on the `ldap_connect` statment shouldn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the PHP documentation - http://php.net/ldap_connect:

```
When OpenLDAP 2.x.x is used, ldap_connect() will always return a resource as
it does not actually connect but just initializes the connecting parameters.
The actual connect happens with the next calls to ldap_* funcs, usually with
ldap_bind().
```